# Azure App Service setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development result in 404

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.2

I notice this issue when I deploy my asp.net core MVC application docker image to Azure App Service. Either setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Dockerfile `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development` or setting in docker-compose

```
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

I always get 404 when accessing website.

The weird part is that if I set ***ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT*** to any other value (Staging, Production, etc.), 404 will be gone and website can be accessed normally

How to reproduce:

1. Create a asp.net core MVC project (just create a bare bone project, don't change any code or add any logic)
2. Build this project on local machine (Dockerfile is like below)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
# Copy necessary files and restore
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
# Start
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CICDTesting.dll"]
```

3. Push this image to Azure container registry
4. I have a webhook attached with App Service, so deployment will be triggered automatically
5. From the Log Stream I can see the image is pulled successfully and container is up and running
6. Access the website, then it gives 404
7. If I change ***ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development*** to ***ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Staging***, and repeat build and deploy steps, website will be accessible.

It's the same if I remove ***ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development*** from Dockerfile and configure it in docker-compose

Comment: Hi @smoothwood, saw your question posted hear as well as MSDN. I've been trying the same thing but running into my own share of problems. Does your image run locally with the environment set to Development?

One callout is Microsoft has their images posted under mcr.microsoft.com/. Don't think it's an image issue but a good place to start.

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT, thank you, yes, my image run locally perfectly fine. Before I pushed the image to container registry, I first built the image on my local machine and tested, it was running without any issue. That's why I am thinking this issue is related to Azure/App Service.

Comment: Give it another shot. If this is a demo app, trying creating a new ACR and pushing your image there. I created a new ACR and deployed the image and http://ryhilldockerdemo.azurewebsites.net/ is showing Development as the environment name. One thing that's different between our [images](https://gist.github.com/RyanHill-MSFT/bb5143c15354fecfbff2323394b08c06) is I'm exposing the ports and using a different base image,

Comment: Hi @smoothwood, I wanted to follow up with you to see if you were still experience this isuse.

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT thank you very much for your reply, will check and feedback, sorry for delay, quite busy on project.